# how can I swipe more than two views in the same direction? Is it possible to pass the same amount of data while swiping to other views?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have written the following code which i have referred from different blogs and sites and there are no errors..still i am not getting appropriate output. Also tried adding some other codes in the code below. Not sure what's wrong with it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view3: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipe1(sender:)))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipe1(sender:)))

       leftSwipe.direction = .left
       rightSwipe.direction = .right

       view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe1)
       view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe1)

    }

    @objc func handleSwipe1(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if(sender.direction == .left){
            let position = CGPoint(x: self.view3.frame.origin.x - 400.0, y: self.view3.frame.origin.y)
            view3.frame = CGRect(x: position.x, y: position.y, width: self.view3.frame.size.width, height: self.view3.frame.size.height)
        }

        if(sender.direction == .left){
            let position = CGPoint(x: self.view2.frame.origin.x - 400.0, y: self.view3.frame.origin.y)
            view3.frame = CGRect(x: position.x, y: position.y, width: self.view3.frame.size.width, height: self.view3.frame.size.height)
        }

        if(sender.direction == .right){
            let position = CGPoint(x: self.view3.frame.origin.x + 400.0, y: self.view3.frame.origin.y)
            view3.frame = CGRect(x: position.x, y: position.y, width: self.view3.frame.size.width, height: self.view3.frame.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your second .left condition, do you want to move view2 or view3?

Comment: yes I want to move the views in both left and right direction. Actually I have several views on a single view controller. So I want to view the views by swiping them left and right

Comment: Are we supposed to know what you are trying to accomplish by titling "swipe more than two views" and a basically some code? What's the view hierarchy? A *single* swipe gesture is good for **one** view - and (of course) their subviews. Or are you asking about passing data with the swipe - which is a second (and should be a separate) question.

Comment: @dfd I have recently started learning about swift. So don't know the exact object name what to call it. Also I'm new to stack overflow.Can we use swipe gesture on multiple views? I'll make sure not to ask more than one question henceforth. Thank you for your response and pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: @Saurabh swiping views left and right... maybe you should use UICollectionView instead of adding views manually.

Comment: @koropok Ok I will try using UICollectionView instead but can I be able to pass data in UICollectionView? As the data I have stored is in JSON format and want to use some elements in one view and other few elements in other and so on. So is it possible to distribute JSON data in different view?

Comment: @Saurabh yes i don't see why not. your json will be stored in the view controller, so whatever you want to pass into your collection view cell is entirely up to you.

Comment: @koropok Ok Thank you. Can you show me a sample code like how to do it? I have stored my JSON data in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Registering UICollectionViewCell (assuming you are not using any custom cells)

```
self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "mycell")
```

Set your delegate and dataSource for UICollectionView

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
```

Return the number of cells base on your jsonArray count

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.jsonArray.count
}
```

Populate your UICollectionView from your jsonArray

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mycell", for: indexPath)

     // Give what ever data to your cell
     // cell.titleLabel.text = self.jsonArray[indexPath.row] // Use indexPath.Row for the correct index of the jsonArray
     return cell
}
```

There are tons of SO questions on how to use a custom UICollectioView Cell. 
Just a random search for one of them: 
[how to use custom cell in collection view controller in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257423/how-to-use-custom-cell-in-collection-view-controller-in-swift-3)

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried the above code which works just fine.